# Are firefighters forbidden from talking about Grenfell Tower?

Tags: united-kingdom

According to this [Mirror article](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/heroic-grenfell-tower-firefighters-gagged-10722903):

> One firefighter, who did not want to be named, told the Sunday Mirror: “We’ve been told by our management don’t speak, ideally. The coroner has said it could obstruct the investigation. I don’t know how it can – what’s happened has happened, but that’s what we’re being told.”

Have the management of the firefighters forbidden them from speaking out about this disaster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BBC appears to confirm this. Their article [Grenfell firefighters 'hampered by equipment'](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-40535417) says,

> Firefighters have been told not to talk to the media but Newsnight obtained a copy of the "incident mobilisation list", the document which details every appliance dispatched to the incident.
>
> The programme was also sent anonymous accounts from a number of men and women involved in the operation.

Comment: If the OP doubts a newspaper, how does citing another settle the question in any significant way?

Comment: I was just hoping that the BBC would be seen as more authoritative/reliable than the Mirror.